# Good Tutorial for Resharper Templates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, resharper

I'm looking to get into some of the more advanced features of resharper tamplates. I know just enough to be dangerous by looking at some of the existing templates.

What are some of the more advanced features beyond using a variable name in between dollar signs and using $END$ to show where your cursor goes?

What are some good sources on Resharper templates?

Comment: http://programmingsolved.blogspot.com/2014/04/snippet-away.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Resharper PowerToys [sample code](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/PowerToys+Sources) has a project that demonstrates how to use the OpenAPI to create your own custom macro that can be assigned to any $variable$ in a template.

Another built in variable is $SELECTION$ which is handy for creating Surround With templates.

And [here's](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Index.html?permalink) the complete Resharper template authoring reference.